# Delete files uploaded in external Disk(DigitalOcean) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, digital-ocean, delete-file

I'm using digital ocean(do) to save files and not storage in my server, by now I can upload files without problem, but I need delete the files uploaded and not only in the DB, I have been trying delet it with:

```
Storage::delete('url/to/file');
unset('url/to/file);
```

but this doesn't work.

This is my code

```
$upload = Upload::find($id);
$upload->delete();
Storage::delete($upload->getVideo()); //it doesn't give me any mistakes
//$upload->getVideo(); retun the url
$upload->delete();
```

To upload files I'm using this code:

```
$path = Storage::disk('do')->putFileAs( $order->user->hash, $request->file('file'), bin2hex(random_bytes(24)).'.'.$extencion, 'public');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the path (same one you used for upload) to the delete function in order to delete files from your Digital Ocean Space

```php
Storage::disk('digital-ocean')->delete('path/to/file.jpg');
```

It would be a security issue if anyone could delete the file by just getting the URL you use to publicly serve the file

From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#deleting-files)

#### Deleting Files

The `delete` method accepts a single filename or an array of files to remove from the disk:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::delete('file.jpg');

Storage::delete(['file.jpg', 'file2.jpg']);
```

If necessary, you may specify the disk that the file should be deleted from:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('s3')->delete('folder_path/file_name.jpg');
```

Comment: Yes, this works, my mistake was to put the complete url in the delete method.

Comment: Glad I could help, please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't aware full path is not working. For getting the image folder path, use this code "parse_url($image_url, PHP_URL_PATH)"